# Is viewDidUnload & didReceiveMemoryWarning optional?

Tags: ios, ios5

Is the `viewDidUnload` & `didReceiveMemoryWarning` optional if no extra logic is added to these 2 functions (i.e. save to remove the following codes)?

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, if no extra logic is added to these 2 functions.

But you need to inspect carefully the whether any logic is necessary?

You also need to understand when these function is run in this document by Apple

[The View Controller Life Cycle](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html)

Then you decide whether you need any extra logic.

Comment: Oh, it seems that Apple makes changes to theirs iOS SDK, then they change the docs too. I took a check further, then see that `viewDidUnload` is no longer valid (it's deprecated) https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621383-viewdidunload . It means this question and answer is longer valid. Anw, you can check the docs for `didReceiveMemoryWarning` here: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621409-didreceivememorywarning

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html), the default implementation of `didReceiveMemoryWarning`  "attempts to release the view controller’s view". So if you don't need anything else to happen, then you can delete the code and rely on the default.